# django apps on ports over uWSGI

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

One of my django apps is running ok if I run it on port directly

```
# uwsgi --http :8000 --home /home/hsn/Env/site --chdir /home/hsn/djangy/site -w Blog.wsgi
```

But when I run it over a webserver with reverse proxy settings with socket, I get internal server error

is there anything wrong with socket configuration & need I move to port method instead??

here is tree structure of my app..

```
# tree -L 2 djangy/site/
djangy/site/
├── account
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── apps
│   ├── blog
│   ├── blogs
│   ├── gallery
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myapp
│   ├── mysensing
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── qrcreate
├── Blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── images
│   ├── preview2.2.png
│   └── preview.png
├── LICENSE.md
├── manage.py
```

**uWSGI site configuration**

```
# cat site.ini
[uwsgi]
project = site
uid = hsn
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/djangy/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).Blog.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
req-logger = file:/tmp/reqlog
logger = file:/tmp/errlog
```

**nginx site configuration**

```
# cat site.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.vm www.site.vm;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/hsn/djangy/site;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Also if I long list the socket file, it shows = sign next to filename like this

```
# ls -l /run/uwsgi/site.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 hsn www-data 0 May 13 09:15 /run/uwsgi/site.sock=
```

Does it mean something??

now the question part, if socket is not working, should I move to port method over uwgsi?? and how'd be the way to do it??

I get this error when I read `/tmp/errlog` file

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

Comment: But nginx is looking for the port, not the socket.

Comment: `uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:8000;` says you configured nginx to proxy to port 8000, but you should proxy to the socket you created.

Comment: @dirkgroten I've used socket too but is giving Internal Server error. Parameter would be uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/site.sock;

Comment: and what is the exact error? can you look at the nginx logs?

Comment: @dirkgroten over socket it shows internal server error. nginx logs are surprisingly silent, in access log it shows 500 code without any further trace.

Comment: then it's uWSGI or Django returning the 500 error. What do the uwsgi and django logs say?

Comment: @dirkgroten uWSGI logs are not created, also I can't find djano logs, where is default location for that?

Comment: django logs are where you set them up in settings.py: for production you should setup a 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler' handler and tell it where to save the log.

Comment: For uwsgi, you should add a `logger` setting to your site.ini file, see [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html#pluggable-loggers)

Comment: ok I updated uWSGI site conf with logger info as indicated in main Q now, and when I tail the /tmp/errlog file, I get following error.

Comment: --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...

Comment: btw I did not start project with .=manage.py command, rather just copied contents of an existing django project, but it should work hence it shows default page when I run uwsgi command with all parameteres in command prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193249/discussion-between-sollosa-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried with different parameters and it seems issue was with site.ini file

the directive needs I replaced was

`module = %(project).Blog.wsgi:application` with `module = Blog.wsgi`